# Associate an 'event' content type with a 'project' content type

Tags: entities

I have a project content type that can be created by users with certain permissions. I want these users to also be able to create 'events' that are associated with these project content types. So for example, A user who creates a project can create events for that project. I was thinking about putting a entityreference autocomplete field on the event content type that looked up projects created by that user (or could be people who have edit permissions on that content type). Does this  sound like a good way to do this or is there a more standard way to achieve this?

Comment: As always, there are many ways. Drupal does not impose "standards" on it's user, so your question don't really have an answer. You know a way and it's pretty solid way, if you have a problem, ask about that problem and we'll be happy to help (and earn reputation ;) ). But this seems better for forums than Q&A.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all i totally agree with Molot's comment.

Just to help i will provide my opinion on how to do this:

Use the [Node reference url widget](http://www.drupal.org/project/nodereference_URL) module in combination with the [Field Permissions](http://drupal.org/project/field_permissions) module. With the 1st you can create an "Add an Event" link for every Project node and set the fallback behaviour of the field as autocomplete and with the 2nd you can set the permissions for that node reference field.

Comment: I was thinking to use entityreference_autocomplete with a callback setting on the field that calls a hook_menu and does an entityfieldquery look up. User and node can be passed as args to the menu.

Comment: Your approach seems correct but as Molot said follow your way and if you ever stumble to a problem or difficulty post a more specific question and i'm sure someone will help.